# Node Fails To Get Class From An Imported module

Tags: javascript

When I run this, node throws back that the variable trackNames is undefined. I tried other classes from that module and non of them work either. I have a script running thats almost exactly the same to this one and can read from the module fine. How should I fix this?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const readline = require('readline');
const en = require('./elementNames');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin, 
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

let getTracks = async (trackName) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let url = `https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=${trackName}`;
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    return await page.evaluate((trackNames) => {
        let trackSearchResults = [];

        document.querySelectorAll(trackNames).forEach(name => {
            trackSearchResults.push(name.innerText);
        });

        return trackSearchResults;
    }, en.searchTracks.trackNames)
}

module.exports = {
    searchTracks: () => {
        rl.question("Search for a track: ", async (inputTrack) => {
            let trackNames = await getTracks(inputTrack);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you call `getArtist()` function ?

Comment: I call it in node's module.exports class, in a readline.question function.

Comment: what line is it undefined on?

Comment: looks like you have too many awaits as well...  why do you need to await here `return await page.evaluate`?  not sure that is root cause... but it isn't likely correct...

Comment: I solved the issue, for some reason I added that script above to my classNames file, `const searchTracks = require("./searchTracks")`, and the name of the module was overriding the className 'trackNames'. I'm new to posting on stack overflow, how do I delete this post?